# jQuery Mobile and Phonegap ontouchmove preventDefault for video tag?

Tags: jquery, video, mobile, cordova

I use this to stop scrolling/bouncing in my webapp for my ipad when someone tries to tap and drag the page.  It works fine.
jQuery().ready(function(){ document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); } });

The problem is it does not seem to apply to video tags.  Anyone know how to stop scrolling/dragging when the user clicks/drags a video too?  I'm not very good with objective C so I don't know how to extend UIViewController I think it is...

Thanks for any help.